# JavaFx how to hide popup when mouse is clicked on owner window?

Tags: popup, javafx-2

Hi i have javafx app which has only one stage.On tab key press event of text field, a popup showed on primary stage of application. like below

```
    private void tripNoKeyPressEventAction(KeyEvent event){
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB || event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                popup.show(GateIn.primaryStage);
            }
        }
popup.requestFocus();
        popup.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>
        () {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
               if(t1==false)
               {
                   System.out.println("focus lost");
                   popup.hide();
               }
            }
        });
```

I don't click on the popup and don't select anything in popup. I will just click on the stage behind it.I expect popup to be closed but It gives me IllegalArgumentException before executing popup's focusedProperty Listener.

If popup is on a different stage (other than primary stage of aaplication),based on stage focusedProperty() i can hide popup.
How to hide popup in case popup is shown on primary stage?

Answer (score 4):

With FX 8, you can simply do

```
popup.setAutoHide(true)
```

Comment: It makes it invisible. Can I make it visible but take away focus? (it is currently stealing all keyboard event even though I have clicked outside)

Answer (score 1):

You should set a event dispatcher for most top level window then all event will cross it.

In the popup window:

```
getScene().getWindow().setEventDispatcher((event, tail) -> {
        if (event.getEventType() == RedirectedEvent.REDIRECTED) {
            //  RedirectedEvent is a box that contains original event from other target
            RedirectedEvent ev = (RedirectedEvent) event;
            if (ev.getOriginalEvent().getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                hide();
            }
        }else {
            //  if click in the popup window. handle the event by default
            tail.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        return null;
    });
```

More information please see  **[javafx.event.EventDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/event/EventDispatcher.html)**

Comment: This is an interesting solution but in current JavaFX version RedirectedEvent is part of the private API  
It's still detectable by using "event.getEventType().getName().equals("REDIRECTED")", but getOriginalEvent() is unusable